# Shell script - Couldn't find 'fi' for this 'if'

Tags: shell, shell-script, for

I have found this error alongside couple more. I believe that the nesting is not quite all right or the for is not correctly indented or without some semicolon. Either way I have tried for quite some time to figure it out, but to no avail. Here is the code:

```
if [ "${runcmd}" != "echo" ]; then
statusmsg "Kernels built from ${kernelconf}:"
kernlist=$(awk '$1 == "config" { print $2 }' ${kernelconfpath}) for kern in ${kernlist:-netbsd}; do
[ -f "${kernelbuildpath}/${kern}" ] && \
echo " ${kernelbuildpath}/${kern}"
done | tee -a "${results}"
fi
```

It is part of a build.sh file.

Comment: not sure I agree with @PSkocik `var=value cmd ar1`  is a valid syntax. yet I would start with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

`var=value cmd ar1`

syntax doesn't quite seem to work if `cmd` is a for loop (in neither `bash` nor `sh`).

Both `sh` and `bash` give syntax errors for:

```
foo=bar for f in ${foo:-BAR}; do echo $f; done
```

which is what you're esentially doing.

(

- sh: 1: for: not found
- bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

)

And that error seems to result in a `couldn't find fi` error in your case;

Setting the variable on a separate line fixes the syntax error:

```
kernlist=$(awk '$1 == "config" { print $2 }' ${kernelconfpath})
for kern in ${kernlist:-netbsd}; do #...
```

**Note:**

I would just write `"$kernelbuildpath/$kern"` instead of `"${kernelbuildpath}/${kern}"` if I were you.  There's no technical reason for the curlies.

Comment: IIRC, this is true for all built-in commands.  `var=value cmd` only works for external commands.  and some cases are worse than `for` or `while`, e.g. silent failure on `foo=bar test "$foo" = "bar" && echo true`.  AFAICT, foo isn't even set to equal 'bar' in that situation.  `foo=bar ; test "$foo" = "bar" && echo true` works, of course.

Comment: @cas `foo=bar /usr/bin/test "$foo" = bar && echo true` wouldn't work either. The issue is with passing the variable as an argument. Now in my experience, `foo=bar someBuiltingAccessing_foo args` generally works (at least in `bash`) if the builtin makes accomodations for it (by calling `maybe_make_export_env ();` to flush exported variables)